# Migrating from MySQL to MariaDB

Tags: mysql, migration, mariadb

I am migrating my database to MySQL to MariaDB. I have binary storage engine in MySQL and MariaDB does not support it.

How can I convert this to make sure my tables will works? Thank You

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If this is a binary engine that works with MySQL and you have the source for it, then you should be able to easily port it to MariaDB:

- The storage engine interface is 99 % identical. We have mainly move
  some functionality from the storage engine (like statistic counting)
  to the handler interface which should be trivial to fix.
- A few server functions may have changed names, but nothing that
  should not be almost trivial to figure out.

In practice one should be able to port a storage engine for MySQL to MariaDB within 30 minutes or so.

If you don't have the source code, you need to ask the vendor for the storage engine to support MySQL. They should be able to do that without much trouble (as long it's a true plugg-in storage engine and not something that makes big changes to the MySQL/MariaDB upper level code).